# Angular ng-repeat on dynamic numeric keys not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to loop over on below data

`[{"5+":[2,1,3]},{"3-5":[0,1,0]},{"1-3":[1,0,3]},{"0.5":[0,0,0]},{"<30":[0,0,0]}]`

using below code piece

```
<tr ng-repeat='sessionLength in [{"5+":[2,1,3]},{"3-5":[0,1,0]},{"1-3":[1,0,3]},{"0.5":[0,0,0]},{"<30":[0,0,0]}]'>
                                          <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in sessionLength">
                                              {{key}}
                                          </td>
                                          <td ng-repeat="(k,v) in sessionLength['5+']" ng-if="sessionLength['5+']">
                                            {{v}}
                                          </td>
                                          <td ng-repeat="(k,v) in sessionLength['3-5']" ng-if="sessionLength['3-5']">
                                            {{v}}
                                          </td>
                                          <td ng-repeat="(k,v) in sessionLength['1-3']" ng-if="sessionLength['1-3']">
                                            {{v}}
                                          </td>
                                          <td ng-repeat="(k,v) in sessionLength['0.5']" ng-if="sessionLength['5']">
                                            {{v}}
                                          </td>
                                          <td ng-repeat="(k,v) in sessionLength['<30']" ng-if="sessionLength['<30']">
                                            {{v}}
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
```

And below is what i want as an output

```
     App1 App2 App3
5+  : 2    1    3
3-5 : 0    1    0 
1-3 : 1    0    3
0.5 : 0    0    0 
<30 : 0    0    0
```

Need some help with above looping. I am not getting as above mentioned expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You could have three `ng-repeat` one for `tbody` then tr & td respectively, But for larger collection this approach would make performance imact.

In such case you should create custom filter which will return a formatted data which will reduce you `ng-repeat`'s.

**Markup**

```
<thead>
   <th></th>
   <th>App1</th>
   <th>App2</th>
   <th>App3</th>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="(sessionKey, session) in sessionLength">
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in session track by $index">
      <td>{{key}} :</td>
      <td ng-repeat="v in value"> {{ v}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: the main tr loop through this data array 
                                        [{"5+":[2,1,3]},{"3-5":[0,1,0]},{"1-3":[1,0,3]},{"0.5":[0,0,0]},{"<30":[0,0,0]}]
                                        and the sessionLength array contains object with their respective key so your peice of code does not work on that structure

Comment: Thnx for helping me out. But updated solution is not working.

Comment: There should be track by $index because it dupes the array loop. So i implemented track by $index then its perfect. Thank you for get me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate values in the sessionLength arrays so you need to use [track by $index](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to avoid a "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed" error. This should work...

```
       <tr ng-repeat='sessionLength in [{"5+":[2,1,3]},{"3-5":[0,1,0]},{"1-3":[1,0,3]},{"0.5":[0,0,0]},{"<30":[0,0,0]}]'>
                <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in sessionLength">
                    {{key}}
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="(k,v) in sessionLength['5+'] track by $index" ng-if="sessionLength['5+']">
                    {{v}}
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="(k,v) in sessionLength['3-5'] track by $index" ng-if="sessionLength['3-5']">
                    {{v}}
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="(k,v) in sessionLength['1-3'] track by $index" ng-if="sessionLength['1-3']">
                    {{v}}
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="(k,v) in sessionLength['0.5'] track by $index" ng-if="sessionLength['0.5']">
                    {{v}}
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="(k,v) in sessionLength['<30'] track by $index" ng-if="sessionLength['<30']">
                    {{v}}
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: This works for me. But is their any other more clean way of doing same.

Answer (score 0):

@Pankaj Parkar Below is what i have used at the end.
Which is working fine.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(sessionKey, session) in compAppsData">
                                        <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in session track by $index">
                                          <td>{{key}}</td>
                                          <td ng-repeat="v in value track by $index" style="text-align:center"> {{ v}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
```